# 2% available(plugged in not charging) on window 10 on my hp pro book

Tags: battery

on wednesday morning i opened my computer as usually and i found my battery drained and when i plugged the ac charger it started and then it was showing the message plugged in not charging first i thought may be the school sockets are bad but when i got home it was still the same  i tried the methods of shutting and the remove battery and ac and  turn on unistall bla bla bla yesterday but it didnt work and still today it havent worked yet can u help me out is there any other methods i changed the ac adapter or (power cable) but still no change..please get back to me as soon as possible

Comment: "turn on uninstall bla bla bla yesterday" - This is not a helpful description of what happened.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Suggestions for improving your question : include the specific model number and age of the hp pro book.  Use capitalization, punctuation, and ordered lists to make the question more readable.  Please rewrite to take out pronouns and 'bla bla bla'.  Please look up HP battery diagnostic, run it, and add the results to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the laptop off and leave it off but plugged in and charging for half an hour to an hour. If it is still at 2% after you turn it back on then you need to buy a new battery.

Comment: Or the battery needs to be recalibrated...

Comment: @LPChip Or that. If they're unable to turn it on without the AC connected then it's probably the battery.

Comment: Agreed. But lets be thorough and mention every possible option.

Comment: Aye, nothing wrong with being thorough. Cover all the bases and all that... ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your battery needs to be recalibrated.

Basically what happens is that your computer thinks the battery is at 2% full, while it is actually fully charged. In order to recalibrate a battery, you need to first fully drain the battery up to the point where it will no longer turn on.

You may want to boot into the BIOS for this and just leave it there. The BIOS has no auto power down so it will not put the laptop into a suspension setting to conserve power.

Once the battery is fully drained and the pc turned off, press the on button as often as needed until the on button no longer works either.

Now comes the crucial part. You need to charge the device back up to 100% in one charge. So once you plugin the power, make sure that it will continue to charge until windows says its fully charged.

Given that you have drained the battery quite a lot, it is possible that you need to keep the battery and charger connected for at least 15 minutes before you will be able to power on the machine again.

If the device charges up to 2% again and then claims its full, then the battery is really in need for a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Dell laptop, they sent a faulty BIOS update that screwed up AC adapter charging. Check to see when your BIOS was last updated. If it was this week, revert back to an older, stable BIOS update.